# Python If substring exists in string, get its context between relimiters

Tags: python, regex, search, find

I  have a list of strings that follow a pattern such that in some position in the string there may be a substring `RAM`.
ex:

```
sdfjhsk_sdkjfhs_RAM_lkfdgjls
```

Sometimes this string may have another character after it. 
ex:

```
aaaa_RAMA_sfsffgd
```

I'd need to have the whole context between the nearest underscores, so `RAM` in the first case, `RAMA` in the second.

And it may not even exist at all in the string
ex:

```
sfdks_sdfsdf_sdfsdf_sdfsdfsdf
```

Matches at the start or end of the string are allowed:

```
RAMsdoa_saeorfioa_noutd  -> RAMsdoa
aetu_eaei_sdsdf_RAMSdoa  -> RAMsdoa
```

as are matches in strings without underscores:

```
sdasids -> nothing
sdfRAMso -> sdfRAMso
```

What is the best way to search the string and if it contains the pattern `RAM` and if it does, grab everything in between the nearest delimiters `_` (or the start or end of the string, if nearer)?

Comment: What's "best" depends on a number of factors, some of which you are clearly not revealing. What have you tried, and was it too slow or too unflexible?

Comment: What's the desired output for the first string? As there are three underscores `_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression here. You need to match `RAM`, plus any non-`_` characters before and after:

```
import re

def find_ram_context(inputtext):
    match = re.search(r'[^_]*RAM[^_]*', inputtext)
    if match:
        return match.group(0)
```

`[^...]` is a negative character-set match; anything *not* in that set would match. Here that's `_`, and `*` means that there should be zero or more such characters. So any character before or after `RAM` that's not an underscore would be pulled into the matched text.

The function above returns the matched context, or `None` if the word `RAM` is not present:

```
>>> find_ram_context('sdfjhsk_sdkjfhs_RAM_lkfdgjls')
'RAM'
>>> find_ram_context('aaaa_RAMA_sfsffgd')
'RAMA'
>>> find_ram_context('sfdks_sdfsdf_sdfsdf_sdfsdfsdf') is None
True
```

Online demo of the regex with your test cases at https://regex101.com/r/6VcLrC/1

Comment: I'd love to hear what is not helpful or wrong about my answer, to deserve a downvote. That way I can improve my answer!